# EWS - Set Attendees ResponseType for new Appointment

Tags: c#, exchange-server, exchangewebservices, ews-managed-api

I'm working on a project to migrate Calendar items from external server, i'm creating a `Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Appointment` object and then fill/update the properties from the source event(appointment).

For most properties I found the way, but I have a problem with updating the Attendee Response, the meeting i'm migrating has already a response status, e.g. "Accepted,Declined" etc. I want to update the same responses in the target Appointment,

the MeetingResponseType property as shown here: [Attendee.ResponseType property (MSDN)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.attendee.responsetype(v=exchg.80).aspx)
is a read only property:

`public Nullable<MeetingResponseType> ResponseType { get; }`

I tried to find an extended properties for this purpose but has no success,

How can I set/update response status programmatically for each Attendee in the Appointment creation process?

**Some Other Info**

I found that post:

[How Can I Programmatically Set a CalendarItem's attendees to accepted with EWS](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ce2f0bad-fd6e-4fcd-b42a-50d6f4091698/how-can-i-programmatically-set-a-calendaritems-attendees-to-accepted-with-ews?forum=exchangesvrdevelopment)

which suggested [this MSDN Article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exchangewebservices.acceptitemtype(v=exchg.150).aspx)

But I could not found the `AcceptItemType` or `CreateItemType` classes in the `Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.dll` assembly and not anywhere else so I couldn't even check this.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Just a side note here. MS Exchange archiving and searching acts on the creation date from the elements. If you create the new elements by hand they become new elements and such an approach like "archive all elements older then XY days" will not work as expected.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, not critical at the moment, but what are the other possiblities?